# How to get the data from a DateEntry() in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a sort of reminder system but cant figure out how to get the input from the user in a DateEntry.
Im using tkinter and ttkbootstrap
Would love to find the solution to this problem

Here is my code:

```
import time
import tkinter as tk
import ttkbootstrap as ttk
from tkcalendar import Calendar, DateEntry

#define variables
name=''
reminder_date = ''

#Function to save and quit


def confirm():
    name = entry_str.get()
    reminder_date = 
    print(name)
    print(reminder_date)
    reminder.destroy()

#Create the main window
reminder = ttk.Window(themename= "darkly")
reminder.geometry("300x300")

#Text 1
text = ttk.Label(master = reminder, text = "Name of the reminder")
text.pack(pady=15)

#Input field
reminder_name_frame = ttk.Frame(master= reminder)
entry_str = ttk.StringVar()
reminder_name = ttk.Entry(master= reminder_name_frame, textvariable=entry_str)
reminder_name.pack(side="left", padx= 10)
reminder_name_frame.pack(pady=10)

#Time field
date_frame = ttk.Frame(master= reminder)
DateEntry_str = ttk.StringVar()
reminder_date_input = ttk.DateEntry(master= date_frame)
reminder_date_input.pack(side="left", padx=10,)
date_frame.pack(pady= 20)

#Confirm Button
confirm_and_quit_button = ttk.Button(master= reminder, text= "Save and quit", command= confirm)
confirm_and_quit_button.pack()

reminder.mainloop()
```

I tried with .get() but it does it does not exist with DateEntry and i tried .get_date() but I get this error
AttributeError: 'DateEntry' object has no attribute 'get_date'

Comment: `.get_date()` would have worked if you were using the `DateEntry` you imported from `tkcalendar` - but you're using the entirely different implementation from `ttkbootstrap`, instead.  Looks like that one requires you to use `.entry.get()` to retrieve its value.